# Solution for handling check box state handling

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I have list of user and check box for its permission like read, write, add, etc.
This all details are in modals and a search box where we can search user.

Now the issue is whenever I click some checkbox and then search again click some checkbox and search so this should be persisted.

I have try with CSV but when the there is large number of user the CSV data is large so browser get slow and it's performance issue.

I have think on saving it in back end at search time but the situation like a user checkbox clicked sear the same user and click checkbox again and repeat so this can also be overhead.

So I'm looking for solution with no performance issue.

Comment: Not clear at all. If you *change* an user attribute, then search, you are either 1) saving the change or 2) losing the change. If instead you *change* a search attribute, you can permanently or temporarily (at session or request level) saving the new search criteria. Try to explain carefully what you are trying to achieve, and where you are stuck. As it is it's not even understandable if you are saving user data or search preferences

Comment: Seek the performance issue on the backend, you might want to use some pagination to split results on pages.